# TabContainer multiline tabs overlap with content

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer, contenttemplate

I just updated to the December 2013 release of the ajaxtoolkit and I'm very much regretting it.

I have pages with TabContainers that have 2 or 3 lines of tabs. Since updating to the latest toolkit, instead of the tabs' content starting after the 2 or 3 lines, the content starts after the 1st line, creating overlapping tabs & content

Original:
[image]

New Version:
[image]

I haven't been able to find anyone else reporting this, so I'm hoping it's an easy fix that I just don't see.

I can add some blank lines to the content, forcing it down, but some tabs are hidden from some users, making the tab strip into fewer lines, resulting in too much space on the top of the screen. Also, it's a lot of tabs to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the December 2013 release. I downgraded to the October 2013 release and it appeared correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the following css in your code:

.ajax__tab_header
    {
        height: auto !important;
    }

Comment: Thanks, but the release was so buggy it didn't pay. Ended up using the January 2013 release.